# C++ variable with same name, context : global and private,

Tags: c++, private, global

In the following code, g++ gives this error :
1.cpp: In member function `void W::test()':
1.cpp:6: error:`int F::glob' is private
1.cpp:19: error: within this context

But, shouldn't the globally declared
variable 'glob' be used here, instead
of the "private" "glob"?

```
   #include <iostream.h>

    int glob;
    class F
    {
        int glob;
        public:
        void readIt()
        {
            cin >> glob;
        }
    };

    class W : public F
    {
        public:
            void test()
            {
                glob--;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables and functions are accessed using scoping rules, not visbility rules.  Because `F::glob` is the `glob` in the scope of `W::test()`, it is used.  However, `W::test()` does not have access to `F::glob`, and an error results.  The compiler does *not* check for `::glob` because something else preceeds it in scope "priority" (not sure for the exact term).

Answer (score 5):

private glob shadows the global glob,so the error is correct
use ::glob to access the global variable if u intent to use global variable

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `::glob--;` instead. This way you tell the compiler to use the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Class member will be used here, to access global variable use :: operator.